# Download video partial http and response client browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing

How is it generate an actionresult in ASP.NET MVC.

```
public ActionResult LoadVideo()
{
    string file="http://another-server.com/123.mp4";// file is URL Video 
    // how to response a video partial for view in <Video></Video> HTML
}
```

I want view result in HTML

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="/Controller/LoadVideo" type="video/mp4">
 
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

1. Video is big, how can it  send as partial to client browser?
2. Video is 720 , how can convert to 480 and send to browser client?
3. Is it possible to convert .m8u3 ?

Comment: **(1)** It's not clear what is the exact problem... Try to ask about one specific thing (maybe code issues or video editing problem, but **not** all 4 things at once). **(2)** Does your code work to play any mp4 file? Or you need that fixing first? `<source src="/Controller/LoadVideo" type="video/mp4">`

Comment: When I use WebClient to download video. The full movie is first loaded into system RAM and then sent to the browser.
But I want to download this movie in parallel and send it to the browser at the same time.

Comment: See if my answer helps you. No C# here to test..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code but I would expect it to work better like this:

```
public ActionResult LoadVideo()
{
    return Content("http://another-server.com/123.mp4"); //send URL of Video to caller
}
```

Then also your HTML would be like this : 
(where `src` calls the `LoadVideo` function and uses the *returned* response).

```
<source src="@Url.Content("LoadVideo")" type="video/mp4" />
```